# Is it possible to map the member with the getter/setter methods?

Tags: java, reflection

For example, I have some classes with several fields, one of them is as below, I want to output all fields of its instance, however, I must get the mapping between the member name with getter methods, can I get it by reflection ?

```
public class MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter {
private String memberOne;
private int memberTwo;

public String getMemberOne() {
    return memberOne;
}

public void setMemberOne(String memberOne) {
    this.memberOne = memberOne;
}

public int getMemberTwo() {
    return memberTwo;
}

public void setMemberTwo(int memberTwo) {
    this.memberTwo = memberTwo;
}
}
```

Comment: I think it's not clear, what I want is to output all the fields with the member name, for example, I have a output class `public OutputClass<T>{...}` , so that I can use `new output<MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter>` to output the members, note that, at this time I don't know the methods name actually, so I will output all fields with specific order. Could anyone help that how I can do that?

Comment: Generally the explanation needs to become longer to make it more clear, not shorter.

Comment: Is your class follow java bean convention? I mean if member name is "abcd" then getter/setter will always be "getAbcd"/"setAbcd"? Or it is possible in your case to have member "abcd" returned by getter getMeMyPrcoiusAbcdMember? This is not cleat to me

Comment: The mapping between fields and getter/setter methods is a convention. You can't get it unless you check the actual method code. Fields might be named using different convention. For example, in Android they would be called `mField`, with `m` prefix denoting member.

Comment: Yeah, it's follow java bean convention, it's generated by Eclipse. Thanks for your comments @Gimby.

Comment: Remember that generic information is not awailable after you compile your code because of Type Erasure in java (this is only awailable at source code level). So i dont think it is possible to create generic class that takes generic parameter like this new output<MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter> and outputs details of MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter. You have to create method with Class type argument something like void output(Class clsss) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want. With the [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) you can get the [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) and this gives you access to the bean's [PropertyDescriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html).

```
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter.class, Object.class);
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
    String propertyName = propertyDescriptor.getName();
    Method getter = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
    Method setter = propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod();
    Field field = MappingMemberWithGetterOrSetter.class
                .getDeclaredField(propertyName);
    System.out.println("Property " + propertyName + " field:  " + field);
    System.out.println("Getter " + getter);
    System.out.println("Setter " + setter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have a question about it, via your method, I can get the members however how can I get the correspond getter/setter to each memeber ?

Comment: Use `PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod()` and `PropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod()`

Comment: It works, thanks very much. I think learn more about JavaBean is required to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Class aClass = ...//obtain class object
Field[] methods = aClass.getFields(); 

Field field = ... //obtain field object
String fieldName = field.getName();
```

After that you can access getter and setter of the field via

```
Object value = field.get(objectInstance);

field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

where objectInstance is an instance of the class that owns the field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what I want is to find the mapping between the member with the correspond getter/setter method, not set the member to be a value, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getMethods(Class<?> className)
{                   
         Method[] methods = className.getMethods();             
         for(Method method : methods)
            {
           if(method.getDeclaringClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("java.lang.Object") )
             {
                 //Do nothing
             }
             else
             {
                if(StringUtils.startsWith( method.getName(),"get"))
                    {   
                        //Here u ll get all get methods                         
                    }
             }                              
}
```

Comment: I think it works because we can get the mapping by comparing the member name with the method name, however comparing string is not efficient. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

A property in Java is defined by getter and/or setter. If you have a `getLength` method without parameter and with a return value then you have a readable property named `length`. If you have a method called `setLength(Type value)` then you have a writeable property called `length`. If you have both then the property is both readable and writable.

Fields are not involved in the definition of a Java property. How and if you back your properties with fields is up to you.

```
public long getDoubleLength() { return getLength()*2; }
```

constitutes a read-only property of name `doubleLength`. No field exists for this property.

So what you want is not possible in general. If you want to do it for specific own classes where you know this mapping exists or if you want to test other classes for this pattern then you can get methods and fields via reflection and check if fields with the property names exists.

But this may not work all the time. Some people use conventions like `_member` or `mField` for the field names. This is completely on par with the Java Beans definition where properties are defined by getters and setters but will break with the naive approach of matching names.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm trying to understand the logic from you all, my English is limited so I'm slow in returning your messages. Thanks again. Once I get the code which works well I will comment here.

Comment: Yes, I can understand it can't work well all the time, I have this question because I have lots of classes which should output into a .txt file, I want to write a generic FileWriterDao so that it can be good to all classess which order by the specific rules (if member name is "abcd" then getter/setter will always be "getAbcd"/"setAbcd").

Comment: Oh, that is your real problem. Of course there are existing solutions to serialize Java objects to text formats like XML or JSON and of course transformations of those into any other kind of text format (e.g. XSL).

Comment: Your opinion is very valuable. I would consider how to serialize the objects to text formats. However I don't have knowledge on it, highly appreciate if you have some advice on it or recommend some related book. Whatever, thank you for your good point.

Comment: Serialization, especially a generic solution, is not a good topic to start with (we just scratched the surface of one of its problems). I would recommend to look into solutions like JAXB, XStream (both XML) or JSON. They give you a textual representation that you can work with, either on text level or (better) on DOM level to transform it further, either programmatically or via e.g. XSL. XStream is particularly easy to use.

Comment: Good, thanks a lot for your kindly help. I will try to learn that as you said. Thanks.